# Strategies with common methods and data structure

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, strategy-pattern

I am using C++. I have different classes that are basically strategies for doing the same thing. we have the base class `Strategy` from which inherit more advanced strategies. each direct or indirect subclass of `Strategy` has a method `run()`. An advanced strategy will often call , inside its method `run()` , the method `run()` of its parent and then will add some pre or post processing. It might also call it many times, inside a loop.

Now all those strategies are applied on the same `DataStruct`. Indeed the unique `DataStruct` is well definied for each strategy. However within each strategy the meaning of `DataStruct` may not be the same.

Let me give you a simple example: Imagine `StrategyA` does some optimization over a set A while `StrategyAUnionB` does optimization over the set A Union B. `DataStruct.optimalValue` does have a meaning for both but the meaning is not the same.

The easy solution I see now is to put an attribute `dataStruct` of type `DataStruct` in the base class and if a strategy will call the `run()` of a parent class it needs to make a copy of `dataStruct` that it will use to update `dataStruct` after the call to `run()` of the parent class.

I see clearly that this solution is not very clean and I would be grateful if I can get an advice from more experienced programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody is answering, I will give it a try.

I would suggest separating the strategy from the data structure. Whenever you invoke a `run()` of some specific `Strategy`, you would pass it a `DataStruct` object (as a reference) to process and update it. And of course, this will extend through your hierarchy of classes. So that the reference will be passed on until the base class and then finally post processed by the starting function.

This would avoid any ambiguities regarding the meaning of fields in the data structure, since you have to be sure what you mean when you pass it to the function.

Comment: I don't think this solution works because everyone will be modifying the same DataStruct object ... However having a separation between Strategy and Datastruct might be a good idea.